# Delphi XE6 Android - get Android System Time format

Tags: android, delphi, time, system

Can anyone tell me if they know how to get the Android Device System Time (12 or 24 hour)?  I've searched quite a bit an am now trying to import the DateFormat class to get the Is24HourFormat function to return True or False.  I have noticed when calling in JAVA you use 'this' - example if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)) - but I don't know what 'this' would refer to when calling this function from Delphi - i get a thread error when I try to get the default adapter.  Here is my definition in Delphi:

```
Type

  JDateFormat = interface;
  JDateFormatClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{05CE5465-2953-4CC3-9D9B-01D71E90F412}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/text/format/DateFormat')]
  JDateFormat = interface(JObject)
  ['{D5C8CAD6-E717-4B95-89F1-A6FD0861B7DB}']
  function is24hourformat:boolean;
  end;

  TJDateFormat = class(TJavaGenericImport<JDateFormatClass, JDateFormat>) end;
```

.....

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
l_x: JDateFormat;
begin
  l_x := TJDateFormat.Create;
  // determine the Android time format
  if not l_x.is24hourformat then
    timeedit1.Format := 'hh:mm:ss tt'
  else
    timeedit1.Format := 'hh:mm:ss';
  timeedit1.Text := timetostr(now);
end;
```

If anyone has a simpler idea that would be great or if you know how to fix my issue.

Thanks!

PS This is the definition for the function: